# Why don't the fuse connections in programmable ROM cause the whole matrix to be shorted together?

Tags: rom

If the rationale of using diodes in ROM (rather than simple wires) is to prevent the matrix being shorted together, then why does shorting not occur for programmable ROM - which has blowable fuse connections?

Apologies if should not be starting a new thread for this; please note that the question is inspired by an answer here [What is the rationale of using diode matrix in ROM](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/196874/what-is-the-rationale-of-using-diode-matrix-in-rom) , but I don't have sufficient 'rep' to comment my question there.

Comment: Asking a new question and cross-referencing to the old one is the correct procedure on this site. +1.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Fuse-programmable ROM is not a simple wired XY matrix, with fuses at each intersection. That wouldn't work, for the reasons you give.

Typically, transistors are used at each intersection, like this.

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.tankonyvtar.hu/hu/tartalom/tamop412A/2011-0041_digital_technics/ch04s02.html), worth visiting if you're interested in other types of ROM.

Conceptually, something as simple as a diode in series with each fuse would serve to both allow reading, and selection of the appropriate fuse to blow. However, there's a lot of development and technology between the basic idea, and a commercial product. Interestingly, many fuse ROMS use 'anti-fuses'. In the right process, high voltage can punch through the dielectric layer of a capacitor and make it fail short more reliably and cheaply than high current can open a fuse.